# Getting an Adobe Muse website full screen on iPhone?

Tags: ios, iphone, muse

I have created a mobile website on adobe muse & would like it to act like an app once added to the homescreen?

The "meta name web capable content yes" tag will work and acts like a an app in fullscreen mode but only for the homepage; as soon as you click another page it redirects to safari ? Does anyone have any solutions for this ?

Comment: can You explain yourself a bit better? what exactly your app is doing ?
is it only opens a website ?

Comment: From what i understood `UIWebView` will help you with that issues , BUT apple most likely will reject that .

Comment: Sorry, Basically it's just a mobile website but I want it to full screen once added to a ios device screen so in a way it looks like an app ? Hope this is more clear.